# IBM-Bluemix Push migration

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have a Push-Notification service set up that I had to migrate (because IBM is closing the old service).

I used the original app and just opened a new Push-Service.

Now, when I try to test the installation with the REST-API online, it tells me that the app secret isn't valid.

Do I have to open a new app as well? (besides, I can't find the app-secret in the new interface)

What happens to the old mobile apps. Does the service run side by side for a while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app-secret value for the new push service is the VCAP credential, not an overall application secret like it was with the old services. The new services are more decoupled and thus only push requires the secret value at this time (added to prevent malicious usage of the REST API) and it is located in a different spot than in the old services.

Here are the steps to grab the app secret from your new push service instance (taken from: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/t_restapi.html). Note where it says to click Show Credentials this is in reference to the new push service instance tile on your application dashboard's Connections tab.

[image]

With that said I highly recommend migrating completely from your app using the old services (Push, Mobile Data, Mobile Application Security) to a new app using nothing but the new services (Push Notifications, Cloudant NoSQLDB, Mobile Client Access). The services are not intended to work together cross-generation, and should be taken wholesale.